# Why can't I find File > Info > Security Warning?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Svetlana Cheusheva  last updated [How to enable and disable macros in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/03/11/enable-disable-macros-excel/) on June 14 2021.

> #### Turn on macros in Backstage view
>
> Another way to enable macros for a specific workbook is via the Office Backstage view. Here's how:
>
> 1. Click the *File* tab, and then click **Info** in the left menu.
> 2. In the *Security Warning* area, click *Enable Content* > **Enable All Content**.
>
> As with the previous method, your workbook will become a trusted document.

> [image]

I followed these steps, but I don't see "Security Warning" below.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a macro enabled workbook open? Or if you have created macros in your workbook have you saved and reopened it? As far as I know that warning will only appear when opening workbooks from other people.

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel file currently has no macros and or has been enabled, the above tab will not appear.

Please add a macro to your file and save it as an **.xlsm**(Excel Macro-Enable Workbook) file, and then close and re-open it to check.
[image]